# Download a image from SSL using curl?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

How do I download a image from curl (https site)?

File is saved on my computer but why is it blank (0KB)?

```
function save_image($img,$fullpath){
    $ch = curl_init ($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'w');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
}

save_image("https://domain.com/file.jpg","image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```

should actually be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

so curl knows that it should return the data and not echo it out.

Additionally, sometimes you have to do some more work to get SSL certs accepted by curl:
[Using cURL in PHP to access HTTPS (SSL/TLS) protected sites](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)

EDIT:

Given your usage, you should also set CURLOPT_HEADER to false as Alix Axel recommended.

In terms of SSL, I hope you'll take time to read the link I suggested, as there are a few different ways to handle SSL, and the fix Alix recommended may be OK if the data isn't sensitive, but does negate the security, as it forces CURL to accept ANY SERVER CERTS.

Comment: Or just have curl write out directly to the file, saving having to store the binary data in a variable, potentially exceeding PHP's memory limit. see: CURLOPT_FILE

Answer (score 4):

You need to add these options:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Also, set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` and `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`.

Comment: Because this is a terrible approach, to ignore SSL warnings. This is not secure and must not be done that way. Instead you should set up the certificate and download, forcing the SSL if available - always.

Comment: I used the above mentioned options. But still the image size is '0'.

Comment: It woked for me, in my case, not being secure is not an issue