# How to download this PDF file using php

Tags: php

I want to download a pdf file from [this link](https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTReportsAccessController?menukey=15.03.00&locale=en_CA). From the page, select weekly summary, I want download the first pdf.

[PDF](https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA)     Weekly summary - Last week: Sorted by insider

I'm using the following code try to download the pdf,

```
<?php

$file="https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA";

if (file_exists($file))
{
    if (FALSE!== ($handler = fopen($file, 'r')))
    {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); //changed to chunked
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); //Remove

        //Send the content in chunks
        while(false !== ($chunk = fread($handler,4096)))
        {
            echo $chunk;
        }
    }
    exit;
}
echo "<h1>Content error</h1><p>The file does not exist!</p>";


?>
```

**It seems I can not download using PHP. I can download by myself confirm the popup window.  Any suggestions?**

I tried curl also, still can not download. The file size is zero.

```
<?php

    $file="https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA";

    $path = 'c:\download\output.pdf';

    $ch = curl_init($file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents($path, $data);


?>
```

Comment: why not just point clients at the direct url? it's not like you're actually changing anything about the pdf - just proxying it.

Comment: curl would be the usual way theses days

Comment: @MarcB, could you show me how to do that?

Comment: all you're doing is grabbing the pdf and echoing it out. so why not just enter that url directly into your browser, or feed it up as a link on your site?

Comment: @MarcB, I don't need to display it in my website. Just want to download the PDF file.

Comment: @Dagon, I just tried curl to download the file. Please see the updated code, but still can not do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I could download the PDF file with PHP curl and CURLOPT_REFERER setting. Below is the code.

```
<?php

$url  = 'https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA';
$path = "/pdf/output.pdf";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTReportsAccessController?menukey=15.03.00&locale=en_CA');

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$result = file_put_contents($path, $data);

if (!$result) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

Comment: I see only "success" but nothing more. Why browser doesn't start download?

Comment: could you please explain this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTReportsAccessController?menukey=15.03.00&locale=en_CA');

Answer (score 11):

Instead of getting your PHP server to act as a proxy why not just:

```
<?PHP
$file="https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA";
header("Location: $file");
?>
```

Version 2

```
<?PHP
$file="https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA";
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
readfile($file);
?>
```

Version 3

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.sedi.ca/sedi/SVTWeeklySummaryACL?name=W1ALLPDFI&locale=en_CA');
```

Add this line to your original code?

Comment: I just want to download the pdf locally but not display it in my website.

Comment: It seems that this website doesn't like people directly download PDF's I can only guess that you need to set a referral URL or something else. [Hotlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking)

Answer (score 1):

Also, as mentioned here:

[Download a image from SSL using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045384/download-a-image-from-ssl-using-curl)

for https we should add the following:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```