# Download remote PDF

Tags: php, pdf, curl, download

I'm trying to load and save a remote PDF to my server for a project, but the link has no file extension. It's a kind of secured link.

https://www.enablelogistics.com.au/BECPRD/SSOAuth.aspx?SESSION_KEY=F86A56B3-D12C-4E70-AE71-A8A422B3EA4E&LINK_PAGE=ITINERARYENC&TRANS_ID=A25D191B-B098-4F45-9217-FB6D2B70F803

When I open the link in the browser I can download the PDF file, but saving it with my script has no success.

Is there a way to save the PDF on my server with a script?
I tried following code without success:

```
$url ="https://www.enablelogistics.com.au/BECPRD/SSOAuth.aspx?SESSION_KEY=F86A56B3-D12C-4E70-AE71-A8A422B3EA4E&LINK_PAGE=ITINERARYENC&TRANS_ID=A25D191B-B098-4F45-9217-FB6D2B70F803";
getFileContents($url);

function getFileContents($url)
{
// Workaround: Save temp file
$img = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'pdf-');
$img .= '.' . pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$fp = fopen($img, 'w+');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

fclose($fp);

return $result ? $img : false;
}
```

I found the script here : [Downloading a large file using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl)

Comment: Well, for starters you probably don't want to include your session_key in anything you're posting online. Also, did you check the related threads such as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076323/how-to-download-this-pdf-file-using-php ??

Comment: No, I did saw that thread. Thanks I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

To download a file (binary or not) you can use [*file_get_contents()*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).
file_get_contents return the file content into a string.

```
//Download PDF content
$pdfContent = file_get_contents("https://www.enablelogistics.com.au/BECPRD/SSOAuth.aspx?SESSION_KEY=XXXXXXX-DDDD-4444-AAAA-XXXXXXX&LINK_PAGE=ITINERARYENC&TRANS_ID=AAAAAAAA-3333-5555-6666-222222222");

$fileName = "myPDF.pdf";
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
//Write content into the file
fwrite($fp, $pdfContent);
fclose($fp);
```

You can if necessary use options in file_get_contents to specify GET or POST method, Basic Authentication and more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, but your code doesn't saves the PDF im looking for.
It safes a PDF with HTML content :

> WWW.ENABLELOGISTICS Enable Logistics v95.4248
>   Welcome to Enable
>   Logistics Please enter your username and password to sign in.
>   Forgot Password?
> ©2016 Bright People Technologies Pty Ltd

I have no clue how to dowload the pdf to my server.
Clicking the link only let's me download local.